# Getting DeliveredDate from Database

Tags: java, lotus-notes

I wanted to get the **"DeliveredDate"** of email from my local. While looping through my document I'm checking it using `document.hasItem("DeliveredDate")` but returns me nothing.

Screenshot below:

[image: SC]

```
//Search multiple query
docCount = view.FTSearch("Number of Samples: | \"Number of Inquiry:\" | \"Number of Universe:\" | \"Request Type:\"");

doc = view.getFirstDocument(); //Returns the first document in a view.

while(doc != null)
{
   if(doc.hasItem("DeliveredDate"))
   {
       System.out.println(true);
   }
   else
  {
       System.out.println(false);
  }

   doc = view.getNextDocument(doc);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It can actually be empty, try such approach (below logic in @formula).

```
@If(DeliveredDate != ""; DeliveredDate; PostedDate != ""; PostedDate; @Created)
```

Read here for more details (there is info about DeliveredDate and PostedDate):
[Why is the date shown in Inbox folder different from that shown when the document is opened?](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21094593)

**UPDATE**

You should not use doc.getItemValue("DeliveredDate") as field DeliveredDate is Date. Basically you need to work with Item instead (see examples below).
You have 2 options:

```
System.out.println(doc.getFirstItem("DeliveredDate").getText());
```

or

```
System.out.println(doc.getFirstItem("DeliveredDate").getDateTimeValue().getLocalTime())
```

Comment: I tried to check if exists and returns me true but I can't get the values. Even the documents exists. `if(doc.getItemValueString("DeliveredDate") != ""){ System.out.println(doc.getItemValue("DeliveredDate")); }`

Comment: @francisunoxx Ok, I see the issue, I have updated my answer.

Comment: getItemValueString returns null if the item is a date.  Also, you don't want to use != or == for a string comparison, you want .equals()